# How can I send data in binary form over a Java socket?

Tags: java, sockets, binary

I've seen lots of examples of sending serialized data over sockets in Java, but all I want is to send some simple integers and a string. And, the problem is I'm trying to communicate these to a binary written in C.

So, bottom line: how can I just send some bytes over a socket in Java?

Comment: Are you sure the C program and the Java program treat binary ints and strings the same way?  If you're not, send them as plain old text.  If you don't have control of the C program reading the socket then you'll have no choice but to send the data in whatever format it is the C program wants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would really recommend not using the Java Sockets library directly.  I've found Netty (from JBoss) to be really easy to implement and really powerful.  The Netty ChannelBuffer class comes with a whole host of options for writing different data types and of course to can write your own encoders and decoders to write POJOs down the stream if you wish.

This page is a really good starter - I was able to make a fairly sophisticated client/server with custom encoders and decoders in under 30 minutes reading this: http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/guide/html/start.html.

If you really want to use Java sockets.  The socket output stream can be wrapped in a DataOutputStream which allows you to write many different data types as well, for example:

```
new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()).writeInt(5);
```

I hope that's useful.

Comment: DataOutputStream seems to work just fine. My workday is over, I'll get back on this tomorrow.

Comment: Be aware that the link to this tutorial is for the JBoss version of Netty. That doesn't match the API of the netty.io download that the tutorial links to.  Use http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html instead

Answer (score 10):

You can use the simple [OutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream()) given by the [Socket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html).
From there you can [write](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(byte[])) bytes.

If you want you can also encapsulate this stream in a [BufferedOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) to have a buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) for the serialization and [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.com/) for the data transfer.