# JAVACV TCP/IP Connection for sending a stream of images

Tags: java, tcp, tcpclient

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I send data in binary form over a Java socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864959/how-can-i-send-data-in-binary-form-over-a-java-socket)

I am working on an app and want to send images over to a client app through the Internet in JAVA. Basically IplImage data through TCP/IP. So now, its kinda video chat thing. I need both the apps o different PC's as server and client for each other. 
Any ideas ? I am completely lost.

Comment: I am new to StackOverFlow, so I really don't get it .

Comment: @user1026134: see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: @ - if you're new here, the first thing you need to do is learn how to search. Typing "send data over tcp/ip in java" into the search box returned nearly 5,000 results. Here's one answer from that search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864959/how-can-i-send-data-in-binary-form-over-a-java-socket

Comment: I am playing with BufferedImage of javacv and ByteBuffer of image.awt
Do any of you have any idea how this will work ?

Answer (score 0):

You can establish a two connections, 1 for sending the information in one direction, 2 is for sending in opposite direction. So application has to be client for another application and also a server for another application.

Answer (score 0):

TCP connections transfer data both ways.  All boxes need a server and all boxes need to be able to start clients. A user that wants to initate a chat starts a client which calls up, (connects to), the called-party server.  Video can then flow both ways until one party or the other closes the connection.

Is there some particular problem?

Comment: How do I convert IplImage to Bytes ?