# binary file from java to javascript via websocket

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, binary, java-websocket

I have a Java-Server with an open websocket connection to the javascript client.
I want to transfer a binary file from the java server to the javascript client so that the user just has to save the file somewhere in the filesystem.

On client side I could easily handle a Blob.
On server side I have a java.io.File and a javax.websocket.Session.
I could simply write to the `javax.websocket.Session.getBasicRemote().getSendStream()`.

Does anyone have such an example or can tell me if I am right and what I have to do on client side?

Comment: possibly duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864959/how-can-i-send-data-in-binary-form-over-a-java-socket

Comment: @grsdev7 IMHO: websocket != socket & java != javascript